# How do I fetch User post on user timeline?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I have a database containing 3 collections [**Users** (contains registered users), **Userpost** (contains the post of the registered users) while **Profile** (contains their individual profile)].
I was able to link the Profile and Users Schemas to the Userpost Schema with their ObjectId.

What I know at present is how to fetch the Userpost and populate the User and Profile.
What I want to do is to fetch all the post of a single registered user his/her timeline.
What I have tried to the add the Userpost and Profile Schemas to the UserSchema by the ObjectId but each time I make a post, the Userpost on the User collection is always an empty array.

Below are my Schemas please

**User Schema**

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    roles: {
        User: {
            type: Number,
            default: 2001
        },
        Mentor: Number,
        Admin: Number
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    userID: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    refreshToken: String
});

const User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

**Profile Schema**

```
const ProfileSchema = new Schema({

    lastname: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    firstname: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    othernames: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    countries: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    phones: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },  
    User: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user',
        required: true,
    }],   
});

const Profile = mongoose.model('profile', ProfileSchema);

module.exports = Profile;
```

**UserPost Schema**

```
const UserpostSchema = new Schema({
    post: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    Profile: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'profile',
        required: true,
    }],
    User: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user',
        required: true,
    }]
});

const Userpost = mongoose.model('userpost', UserpostSchema);

module.exports = Userpost;
```

**How I populate User and Profile to the UserPost on API**

```
router.get('/getpost/:id', (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    Userpost.find({_id:id}).populate('User').populate('Profile').exec((err,docs) => {
        if(err) throw(err);
        res.json(docs);
    })
});
```

How do I fetch the entire post of a user to his timeline?

Kindly help please.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for u, In UserPost Schema you have taken array for Profile and User which isn't required, and also instead of Schema use mongoose.Schema every where in model.

**User Schema**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   username: {
      type: String,
      required: true
   },
   roles: {
      User: {
         type: Number,
         default: 2001
      },
      Mentor: Number,
      Admin: Number
   },
   password: {
      type: String,
      required: true
   },
   userID: {
      type: String,
      required: true
   },
   refreshToken: String
});

const User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

**Profile Schema**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const ProfileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
lastname: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
firstname: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
othernames: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
countries: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
phones: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
User: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "user",
    required: true,
},
});

const Profile = mongoose.model('profile', ProfileSchema);

module.exports = Profile;
```

**UserPost Schema**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const UserpostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  post: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  Profile: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "profile",
    required: true,
  },
  User: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "user",
    required: true,
  },
});

const Userpost = mongoose.model("userpost", UserpostSchema);

module.exports = Userpost;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Dhaval. This works absolutely well . I am grateful for your help

Comment: great to know it worked, Don't forget to like the answer.

Comment: I have done that already. Thanks. I have an issue though. when I populate, I only get the profile information of the first profile on my profile collection. Irrespective of who logged in. How can I resolve that please?